# Full Calendar not working correctly on ng serve

Tags: angular

i'm trying to do a Calendar in Angular 9 with the FullCalendar library
but when i run the command ng serve , this failed and return me a lot of error message
Someone can help me, please?

this is my code :

- app.module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


//calendar 
import { FullCalendarModule } from '@fullcalendar/angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FullCalendarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

- app.component.ts :

  ```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

  //calendar
  import { CalendarOptions } from '@fullcalendar/core';
  import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    title = 'calendar';


    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit(): void {

    }

    calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
      plugins: [dayGridPlugin],
      initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
      weekends: false,
      events: [
        { title: 'Meeting', start: new Date() }
      ]
    };


  }
  ```
- app.component.html :

  ```
  <full-calendar [options]="calendarOptions">
    <ng-template #eventContent let-arg>
      <b>{{arg.timeText}}</b>
      <i>{{arg.event.title}}</i>
    </ng-template>
  </full-calendar>
  ```

and these are the log :

```
ERROR in node_modules/preact/src/jsx.d.ts:2138:24 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SVGMPathElement'.

2138    mpath: SVGAttributes<SVGMPathElement>;
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/preact/src/jsx.d.ts:2145:22 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SVGSetElement'.

2145    set: SVGAttributes<SVGSetElement>;
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@fullcalendar/angular/full-calendar.component.d.ts:46:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/michael.brunco/Desktop/Calendar_angular_9/calendar/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

46     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<FullCalendarComponent, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@fullcalendar/angular/full-calendar.component.d.ts:47:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/michael.brunco/Desktop/Calendar_angular_9/calendar/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'.

47     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<FullCalendarComponent, "full-calendar", never, { "options": "options"; "deepChangeDetection": "deepChangeDetection"; "events": "events"; "eventSources": "eventSources"; "resources": "resources"; }, {}, ["dayHeaderContent", "dayCellContent", "weekNumberContent", "nowIndicatorContent", "eventContent", "slotLaneContent", "slotLabelContent", "allDayContent", "moreLinkContent", "noEventsContent", "resourceAreaHeaderContent", "resourceGroupLabelContent", "resourceLabelContent", "resourceLaneContent", "resourceGroupLaneContent"], never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@fullcalendar/angular/utils/offscreen-fragment.component.d.ts:8m:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/michael.brunco/Desktop/Calendar_angular_9/calendar/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

8     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<OffscreenFragmentComponent, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@fullcalendar/angular/utils/offscreen-fragment.component.d.ts:9:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/michael.brunco/Desktop/Calendar_angular_9/calendar/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'.

9     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<OffscreenFragmentComponent, "offscreen-fragment", never, {}, {}, never, ["*"]>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@fullcalendar/angular/utils/transport-container.component.d.ts:16:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/michael.brunco/Desktop/Calendar_angular_9/calendar/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

16     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<TransportContainerComponent, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@fullcalendar/angular/utils/transport-container.component.d.ts:17:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/michael.brunco/Desktop/Calendar_angular_9/calendar/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration'.

17     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<TransportContainerComponent, "transport-container", never, { "inPlaceOf": "inPlaceOf"; "reportEl": "reportEl"; "elTag": "elTag"; "elClasses": "elClasses"; "elStyle": "elStyle"; "elAttrs": "elAttrs"; "template": "template"; "renderProps": "renderProps" }, {}, never, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@fullcalendar/angular/full-calendar.module.d.ts:7:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/michael.brunco/Desktop/Calendar_angular_9/calendar/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

7     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<FullCalendarModule, never>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@fullcalendar/angular/full-calendar.module.d.ts:8:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/michael.brunco/Desktop/Calendar_angular_9/calendar/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration'.

8     static ɵmod: i0.ɵɵNgModuleDeclaration<FullCalendarModule, [typeof i1.FullCalendarComponent, typeof i2.OffscreenFragmentComponent, typeof i3.TransportContainerComponent], [typeof i4.CommonModule], [typeof i1.FullCalendarComponent]>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@fullcalendar/angular/full-calendar.module.d.ts:9:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/michael.brunco/Desktop/Calendar_angular_9/calendar/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectorDeclaration'.

9     static ɵinj: i0.ɵɵInjectorDeclaration<FullCalendarModule>;
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

i would to thanks in advance anyone

Answer (score 1):

As stated on [the website](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular), the Angular version of Full Calendar is for Angular 12-15.

Angular 9 is really old, an upgrade in versions in stronly advided.

Comment: ah okok , so, i'll upgrade my angular project